# Problem with max() and min() function

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

I created following table

```
create table Interiors(
no integer,
name varchar,
type varchar,
dateofstock datetime,
price decimal(6,3),
discount numeric(6,2))
```

---

i want to solve these two queries.

1. Display the type, sum of price and average of discount by grouping type as 'baby cot'.
2. Display the type, maximum and minimum of price by grouping type as 'baby cot'.

I wrote following stmts for each resp.

---

1. select type, sum(price), avg(discount) from Interiors group by 'baby cot'.
2. select type, max(price), min(price) from Interiors group by 'baby cot'.

---

I got following error same for both like that 'type is not an aggregate fun. or it dont have GROUP BY' clause. What should I do for solving that queries.

Comment: Is this homework? You should tag as such if it is...

Answer (score 1):

> group by 'baby cot'.

You cant group by a name of something, you have to group by a column name. For instance do:

```
select type, sum(price), avg(discount) from Interiors group by type
or
select type, sum(price), avg(discount) from Interiors where type = 'baby cot' group by type
```

Comment: It's working but only when all type are 'baby cot', it not shows proper output when type having another value in different records.

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by the field name, not the contents.  If you wish to only include the data where the type is 'baby cot', you would include that in the WHERE clause.  For example...

```
SELECT
  type,
  SUM(price) AS "sum",
  AVG(price) AS "avg",
  MAX(price) AS "max",
  MIN(price) AS "min"
FROM
  Interiors
WHERE
  type = 'baby cot'
GROUP BY
  type
```

Comment: If the WHERE clause limits to just one type there's no need for grouping afterward.

Comment: Although it is not *needed*, it is better to be explicit and complete, rather than use shorthand.  Especially in terms of an answer attempting to convey syntax, etc.

Comment: Doing it the explicit way also means that you don't need to specify 'Baby Cot' in the first field of the SELECT, you can just put the *type* field name.  This means that when the code is chaged to search for a different type, it only needs updating in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258901%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

It's the MSDN entry for SQL Server Aggregate Functions. There's plenty of example, including what you're trying to achieve.